# Image tap gesture in Listview not responding

Tags: image, listview, xamarin, button, gesture

I have a Listview group header containing an image button - imgAdd - which is not responding to a tap gesture. I've tried various methods currently available on this topic but nothing seems to work.. Help on this appreciated? I'd like it to trigger a method within the binded viewmodel to navigate to a page - nothing complicated.

`code`

```
                        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate 
                    SeparatorVisibility="Default"><DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell Height="110"  > 
                                <Grid VerticalOptions="Start" >
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="70"/>  
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <!--Headers-->
                                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White"
                                                 HeightRequest="5" > <!--150-->
                                        <!--
                                         <Frame OutlineColor="#FFB607" HasShadow="False" Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                           IsClippedToBounds="False" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                        -->
                                       
                                      
                                            <Label
                                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                                   HeightRequest="70" 
                                                   FontAttributes="None"
                                                   Margin="0,0,0,20"                                       
                                                   FontSize="18"
                                                   Text="{Binding CategoryName}"
                                                   Padding="20,5,0,10"
                                                   TextColor="White"
                                                   BackgroundColor="#FFB607"
                                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                   FontFamily="Hiragino Sans"
                                                   xmlns:local="project.Controls"                                       
                                                   MinimumHeightRequest="70"                                                       
                                                   x:Name="lblTitle"
                                                  />
                                            <Image
                                                Grid.Row="3"
                                                Grid.Column="4"
                                                HeightRequest="30"
                                                WidthRequest="30"
                                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"                                                   
                                                x:Name="imgAdd"
                                                Source="btnAdd.png"
                                                Margin="0,-20,20,0"
                                                >
                                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                     <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource myHomePageViewModel}, Path=ListOnTapCommand}" 
                                                              />                                                        
                                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Image>

                                
                                   </StackLayout>

                                    
                                    <Image x:Name="ImgA" Source="{Binding StateIcon}"  Margin="0,0,25,0"
                                           HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                                    
                                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference homePage},
                                            Path=BindingContext.RefreshLogsCommand}"
                                                              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>                                       

                                </Grid>
                                   <!-- </Frame>-->
                            </ViewCell>
```

`code`

Model

```
public ICommand ListOnTapCommand { get; set;  }


        public myHomePageViewModel()
        {
           ListOnTapCommand = new Command(ListOnTap)
        }

        private void ListOnTap()
        {
            // do something
            App.NavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new search());
        }
 
        private void ListOnTap()
        {
            // do something
            App.NavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new search());
        }
```

Comment: Hi, whether `myHomePageViewModel` is another `ViewModel` that is different with `ListView`'s `ItemSource`? You could share the code of `ContentPage.cs` and the Binded ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Item` model of ListVew **Cell** as follows:

```
public class Item 
{
    public string Name {set; get;}
    ...
}
```

Then **CustomViewModel** could be as follows:

```
public class CustomViewModel : ObservableCollection<Item>
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    
    public ICommand ListOnTapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((e) =>
            {
                var item = (e as Item);
                // deal with Item Model of Tapped Cell
            });
        }
    }      
  
}
```

Now **ContentPage** add CustomViewModel as follows:

```
public partial class GroupedListXaml : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<CustomViewModel> grouped { get; set; }
    public GroupedListXaml ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        grouped = new ObservableCollection<CustomViewModel> ();
        var veggieGroup = new CustomViewModel() { CategoryName = "vegetables" };
        var fruitGroup = new CustomViewModel() { CategoryName = "fruit" };
        veggieGroup.Add (new Item() { Name = "celery", IsReallyAVeggie = true, Comment = "try ants on a log" });
        veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "tomato", ...});
        veggieGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () { Name = "zucchini", ... });
        ...
        fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "banana" , ...});
        fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "strawberry", ...});
        fruitGroup.Add (new VeggieModel () {Name = "cherry", ...});
        grouped.Add (veggieGroup); grouped.Add (fruitGroup);
        lstView.ItemsSource = grouped;
    }
}
```

You could modify **Xaml** code as follows:

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
...
<Grid VerticalOptions="Start"  x:Name="Item">
...
 <Image
      Grid.Row="3"
      Grid.Column="4"
      HeightRequest="30"
      WidthRequest="30"
      HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"                                                   
      x:Name="imgAdd"
      Source="btnAdd.png"
      Margin="0,-20,20,0">
      <Image.GestureRecognizers>
         <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListOnTapCommand}, Path=BindingContext}"
          />                                                        
      </Image.GestureRecognizers>
  </Image>
...
</Grid>
...
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate >
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Jiang, couple of questions, I I added your Item model as above and made the binding changes but the button still doesn't respond. Can you tell me what the TapCommand is referring to?  Is it possible to do this without a model?

Comment: @Avatar I have updated answer, you could have a look when you have time. And if you solved that, remember to mark your answer when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by placing my Label and Image elements within a Grid tag.